# Nginx remove trailing slash from URL

Tags: laravel, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to remove the trailing slash from the URL but somehow it's not working.
I have a Laravel website as the main website and inside a subdirectory, I have installed WordPress. When I'm using `rewrite  ^(.+)/$  $1  permanent; #Remove trailing slash` this code in my server block then Laravel works fine but the WordPress site throws an error as `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

My config file is as follows:

```
server {
    root /var/www/somesite.co.uk/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name somesite.co.uk www.somesite.co.uk;      
    location / {
        rewrite  ^(.+)/$  $1  permanent; #Remove trailing slash
        # redirect non www to www
        if ($host ~ ^(?!www\.)(?<domain>.+)$) {
            return  301 $scheme://www.$domain$request_uri;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location /blog {
        #rewrite  ^(.+)/$  $1  permanent; #Remove trailing slash       
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;        
    }   
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {   
    if ($host = www.somesite.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = somesite.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name somesite.co.uk www.somesite.co.uk;
    listen 80;    
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: You should remove `$uri/` from `try_files` too, as that term is responsible for adding a trailing `/` to some URLs.